# Generate combinations of numpy array elements in one go, and on the fly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I know it's a very trivial question but I couldn't figure out a proper solution. I have two numpy arrays created from two different list of tuples.

```py
    a = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)....])
    b = np.array([(100, 200), (300, 400), (500, 600)....])
```

I have a function that takes two tuples as input and return single value as output

```py
    def myfunc(x, y):
        .....
        return val
```

```py
    vectorized_myfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc, signature='(n),(n)->()')
```

What all I am trying to achieve:

1. Generate all combinations of elements in `a` with every element in `b`. Like `((1, 2), (100, 200)), ((1, 2), (300, 400))..`
2. Pass the generated combinations to `vectorized_myfunc`.
3. What if I want to generate chunks of these combinations on fly and then do 1) and 2)?

PS: I know I can use `itertools.product(..)` but it's very slow.

PPS: I tried using `np.stack(np.meshgrid(a, b), -1).reshape(-1, 2, 3)` and then tried passing it to `vectorized_myfunc` but couldn't get it working

I am open to use `numpy`, `dask` or even `numba` for it

Comment: There is some behaviour that isn't matching what you are looking for. As you create a and b they lost their immutable property. So directly creating a tuple list with tuples isn't possible because they aren't tuple anymore.

Comment: That was a typo. Corrected

Comment: Your Question still includes the np.arrays with tuples. And in the line where you tell what you want to achieve, your wanted result is a tuple of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can work on combinations of indexes of `a` and `b` like so:

```
def product(arrays):
    # the same as itertools.product(*arrays)
    return np.stack(np.meshgrid(*arrays), axis=-1).reshape(-1, len(arrays))

a = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])
b = np.array([(100, 200), (300, 400), (500, 600)])
idx = product([np.arange(len(a)), np.arange(len(b))])
```

Checking:

```
>>> idx
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

I'm not experienced with signatures but the following example works for me:

```
vectorized_myfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: x+y)
>>> vectorized_myfunc(a[idx[:, 0]], b[idx[:, 1]])
array([[101, 202],
      [103, 204],
      [105, 206],
      [301, 402],
      [303, 404],
      [305, 406],
      [501, 602],
      [503, 604],
      [505, 606]])
```

**Update:** I found another example that works with `signature`:

```
vectorized_myfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x,y: np.sum(np.array([x,y])), signature='(j),(j)->()')
>>> vectorized_myfunc(a[idx[:, 0]], b[idx[:, 1]])
array([ 303,  307,  311,  703,  707,  711, 1103, 1107, 1111])
```